# Skip Grub by default on 16.10 - Weird Grub behavior, is /etc/default/grub not being used?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have Ubuntu 16.10 and Win10 installed on the same Inspiron i7559 machine.  I'd like to be able to boot quickly, so I don't want the 10 second wait time.  I'd like my computer to automatically boot whichever OS was booted last time unless I press the <kbd>shift</kbd> key while it's booting, in which case it should show the Grub menu with no timer.  I chose the <kbd>shift</kbd> key because I saw something which sounded like that's the default behavior if you have Grub.  That was supposed to make it simpler.  It didn't.

Here's the relevant part of my `/etcdefault/grub` file.  It's a bit of a mess due to my attempts at solving this with different *Ask Ubuntu* answers:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_FORCE_HIDDEN_MENU="true"
export GRUB_FORCE_HIDDEN_MENU
```

It feels like `/etc/default/grub` is being ignored by `update-grub` in several respects.  The only thing that noticeably changes in grub.cfg when I run `update-grub` is my manually renamed Windows boot options switch back to the generic.

With that file above, I cannot get grub open - it automatically boots the previously booted thing, <kbd>shift</kbd> key or no <kbd>shift</kbd> key.

Without the last two lines, I get all sorts of errors about Grub timeout being allowed or not allowed to be 0.  In any case, booting loads Grub and its set to 10 seconds.  This is because of an if statement in `os-prober` which doesn't let the timeout be 0.  I've tried several solutions offered for older versions of Ubuntu and although I'm unsure of any differences, they did not work.

I also have the following at the end of the file:

```
# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
GRUB_INIT_TUNE="1000 334 1 334 1 0 1 334 1 0 1 261 1 334 1 0 1 392 2 0 4 196 2"
```

This last line is supposed to play some tones before starting grub, but I haven't heard anything.

Some of these things may be possible to fix in grub.cfg, but I'm trying to set up Grub to run the way I want it to in a way that can be impervious to update-grub.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to stop the grub screen as long as you select the os? Use '-1' in Grub_Timeout

Comment: @ArijitChatterjee No.  I want grub to not be shown at all unless I press a key during boot.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=
```

- No value entered after the = sign
- The menu will be displayed for the number of seconds designated by GRUB_TIMEOUT.

This and several other settings are described in the following link.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup

Answer (score 0):

Setting `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` and `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` would lock yourself out from access to the boot-menu. This is a situation which is problematic in multi-boot-environments, even in a single-boot-environment you would have to edit `/etc/default/grub` and run `sudo update-grub` to regain access to the boot-menu if you ever need it. And it could be more difficult to regain access to the boot-menu in a multi-boot-environment depending on the OS which is the default OS to boot. To prevent this undesirable situation the script `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` will reset the time-out to ten seconds if more then one OS is found and GRUB_TIMEOUT is set to zero.

You need to configure Grub to give you at least some time to hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Here a configuration that will fulfill your needs:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=2
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

This configuration gives you two seconds to hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to show the boot-menu, otherwise the default OS will be loaded without showing the boot-menu.